# Кривое масштабирование сайта на мобильных

Tags: html, адаптивная-верстка

Доброго времени! есть сайт [сайт](http://kazakhsouvenirs.kz)

на нем настроен адаптив под мобильную версию и настрое вьювпорт такой

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

но почему то при отображении его на телефоне сайт изначально не замасштабирован на весь экран, отображается только верхний левый уголок
и что бы отобразить его полностью на отдалить масштаб

подскажите что не так с отображением может вьювпорт по другому написать?

Comment: Сайт, сверстанный таблицами! Я думал, что это осталось где-то в уютном 2005-м, где ИЕ6, Пентиум4, Nvidia riva tnt2...

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте свои адаптивные стили, в частности все медиа-выражения:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 900px), only screen and (max-device-width: 900px) { ... }
```

именно в них находится код, который определяет как себя ведут блоки на мобильных устройствах. Там куча стилей, где задаётся ширина блоков в 800 пикселей, отчего главная таблица растягивается до 802 пикселей.

Answer (score 0):

Я использую этот

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Так же может быть еще такое, если в доктайпе прописано что-то типа такого:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Но из-за доктайпа вряд ли.

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день! Меняйте явно заданную ширину в style.css у всех нужных элементов на 100%.Например `#container,#wrappers,.slidetabl` и т.д. так же проверьте скрипт слайдера как то он ширину на 5000 px задает, возможно это неверно.